# review my beginners clojure reverse function

Tags: clojure

I am just starting out in my clojure journey and I wonder if anybody can point out my beginners mistakes in my function below that simply reverses a list.  I know that there is already a reverse function so this is purely for learning.

```
(defn rev
  ([l]
   (if (= (count l) 1) l (rev '() l)))
  ([l orig]
   (if (= (count orig) 0)
     l
     (rev (conj l (first orig)) (rest orig)))))
```

In my defence, it does work but what I  am finding myself doing a lot in clojure is overloading the arguments list to take into account when I need a working list like in this example where I `conj` new items onto.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: It's is [good idea to read tags info](http://take.ms/1atcm) ;-)

Comment: Then why is there a code-review tag?

Comment: @dagda1 to post questions about code review tools?

Comment: Do you really believe that?

Comment: @dagda1 I do really believe that (btw, you can raise the discussion about this on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/))

Comment: @dagda1 This particular question probably would not have been closed by the Clojure sub-community here. Avoid the `code-review` tag and make sure there is a question other than pure code review. See Thumbnail's edit. My vote to reopen (but already answered).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, it's a really good idea to look at the existing implementation of [reverse](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reverse) function first:

```
(defn reverse [coll]
  (reduce conj () coll))
```

The main difference from your code is that existing implementation of `reverse` uses higher-order function [reduce](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce). It's a good practice to use higher-order functions instead of recursion wherever possible.

--

But let's assume that your goal is to learn recursion. Here is how I would've written it:

```
(defn rev
  ([coll]
    (rev coll ()))
  ([coll acc]
    (if-let [[h & ts] (seq coll)]
      (recur ts (conj acc h))
      acc)))
```

Let's have a closer look at my code.

First, I'm using [if-let](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/if-let) and [seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/seq) to check that `coll` is a non-empty collection.

Then I'm using [destructuring](http://blog.jayfields.com/2010/07/clojure-destructuring.html) to get the first element of the given collection and the rest of it.

In other words, my construction

```
(if-let [[h & ts] (seq coll)]
  (recur ts (conj acc h))
  acc)
```

could be rewritten with `if`, `let`, `first` and `rest`:

```
(if-not (empty? coll)
  (let [h  (first coll)
        ts (rest coll)]
    (recur ts (conj acc h)))
  acc)
```

which is almost what you wrote yourself.

The last important thing is that I'm using [recur](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/recur) instead of calling `rev` directly. 
It allow clojure compiler to perform tail recursion optimization.

You should also consider using [loop](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/loop) instead of creating an overloaded function, unless you want to make two-arguments form public:

```
(defn rev [coll]
  (loop [coll coll
         acc  ()]
    (if-let [[h & ts] (seq coll)]
      (recur ts (conj acc h))
      acc)))
```

--

So, there is a lot of things to improve in your code. But I can see only three real mistakes there:

- you should use `recur`;
- there is no point in checking `(= (count l) 1)`;
- you should use [empty?](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/empty_q) instead of `(= (count orig) 0)`.

Here I fixed these two mistakes in your code:

```
(defn rev
  ([l]
   (rev '() l))
  ([l orig]
   (if (empty? orig)
     l
     (recur (conj l (first orig)) (rest orig)))))
```

Comment: @dagda1 I did some editing since your comment. Please, check the final version of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to expose the function with other arities, define and employ them locally:

```
(defn rev [l]
  ((fn rev2 [l orig]
     (if (empty? orig)
       l
       (rev2 (conj (first orig) l) (rest orig))))
   () l))
```

You may find it easier to use `let` or `letfn`:

```
(defn rev [l]
  (letfn [(rev2 [l orig]
             (if (empty? orig)
                l
                (rev2 (conj l (first orig)) (rest orig))))]
    (rev2 () l)))
```

And, by the way, ...

- Don't count the sequence if you just want to know whether there is
  anything in it. Use `seq` or `empty?`.
- Get rid of the special case of 1 element sequences: it isn't special.
- `()` doesn't need quoting.

And, of course, we can and ought to use `recur` instead of the recursive call to `rev2`, to avoid blowing the stack on long sequences:

```
(defn rev [l]
  (letfn [(rev2 [l orig]
             (if (empty? orig)
                l
                (recur (conj l (first orig)) (rest orig))))]
    (rev2 () l)))
```